# Clearing a Material UI search filter TextField and returning to default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am new to ReactJS and pairing it with Material UI is really causing me some roadblocks.  I have created a reusable search filter component for my data tables and it worked exactly the way I wanted, but now I want to add a button to clear the field and show the unfiltered results, as well as return the InputSearch component back to its default state so it will display the label inside the field again, not up in the field’s border as these Material UI TextFields do then they are focused or have a current value. This is where I am hitting my roadblock. I have tried multiple solutions I found online, like using the inputRef/useCallback method to change the values, but it didn’t seem to work…or maybe I misunderstood and did it wrong.  I was also recommended to put my search values to state.   As happens with state my searches are now always one render behind (I.E. , results matching ‘US’ for ‘USA’ ,  ‘USA’ for ‘USAF’, etc…).  Then when I run the handleFilterReset function to set the filter values back to an empty string, nothing happens.  I just want my search filter to work instantly (like it did before I moved the value to state [commented out]) and be able to be cleared, resetting the table back to its default display.
Can someone please help me figure this out? Suggestions are appreciated, but code snippets are much more helpful since I am really new to React and especially Material UI.

***dataTable.js***

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('')
const [searchFn, setSearchFn,] = useState({ fn: items => { return items; } });

// Searching Data 

const handleSearch = e => {
   setInputValue(e.target.value) // value displayed in input field
   let query = (e.target.value).toString().toLowerCase();
   setSearchFn({
        fn: items => {
            if (query  === "")
                return items;
            else    
                return items.filter(x => 
                    (x.tankName !== null && x.tankName.toLowerCase().includes(query)) ||
                    (x.dimensions !== null && x.dimensions.toLowerCase().includes(query)) 
                )
        }
    })
}

// Clearing Filters
const handleFilterReset = () => {
    setInputValue('');
    setSearchFn({fn: items => {return items;}})
};

// Search and filter Inputs
    <div>
        <InputSearch 
            value={inputValue}
            onChange={handleSearch}
        />
        <Button
            text="Reset" 
             onClick={handleFilterReset}
         />
    </div>
```

***InputSearch.js***

```
export default function InputSearch(props) {
    const { inputRef, name, value, error=null, onChange, ...other } = props;

    return (
        <TextField
            label="Search..."
            name={name}
            value={value}
            onChange={onChange}
            {...other}
            {...(error && {error:true, helperText:error})}
        >
        </TextField>
    )
}
```

Comment: What you need to do is create a filteredResult data and an unfiltered one. When the text is present inside the search show filteredResult and when not just show unfiltered one

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion innocent, it pointed me towards a solution that worked out great for me,

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the value to `InputSearch`

Heres an example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-brook-durbvd?file=/demo.tsx

React has a pretty good introduction on its site.
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The code has been updated with a solution to this issue.  I created a display value for the input that I passed to state, which was set to a blank string when the reset is pressed as well as passing an unfiltered data set.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).